# Coroutine in Extension Method

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, coroutine, unity-components

I wrote an extension method to make an object move over time.  It works well; however, because the object is performing that task over a period of time, it is ignoring all other calls, such as my update method.  I am assuming I need to do something with a Coroutine, but I cannot figure out where it goes.  How can I make the following code work without preventing other code (such as the Update() method) from running simulateneously?  The simplified version is as follows:

==================================================================================

```
//The following script is attached to the GameObject
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D)]
public class MyBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody2D.MoveOverTime();
    }

    void Update(){
        rigidbody2D.MovePosition(transform.position.x + 1, transform.position.y);
    }
}
```

==================================================================================

```
//The following script is not attached to anything
public static class Rigidbody2DExtension
{
    public static void MoveOverTime(this Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D)
    {
       gameObject.addComponent<MoveOverTimeComponent>();
    }
}

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D)]
class MoveOverTimeComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update(){
        MovePositionByALittleBit();
    }

    void MovePositionByALittleBit(){
        float x = transform.position.x + 1;
        float y = transform.position.y;
        rigidbody2D.MovePosition(new Vector2(x, y));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would your `Update` method(s) be called?  They're never invoked as far as I can see.

Comment: @KirkWoll They are called automatically as an extension of MonoBehaviour

Comment: How?  You aren't overriding the method and it's private.

Comment: @KirkWoll Honestly, I don't know. It is just a Unity thing. `Update()` is just called every frame when extending `MonoBehaviour`. `Start()` is called on creation. Creation of a `MonoBehaviour` happens when `AddComponent<T>()` is called (like `MoveOverTimeComponent`) or it is attached in the engine (like `MyBehavior`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your `Updates()` are running. In fact, all the `Updates()` of all the `MonoBehaviours` will run.

Assuming that `gameObject.addComponent<MoveOverTimeComponent>();` actually refers to a `GameObject` (which is not clear by the limited code you posted) then your problem is trying to move the same `GameObject` on two different `Update()` functions.

Comment: That is my problem, thank you!  I am trying to move the same `GameObject` on two different `Update()` functions.  Any idea on how to allow this?

Comment: You are already moving, it just happens that you move in the same direction by same exact amount. Make one of the `Updates()` move only on the `y-axis` and the other on the `x-axis` so you can see the drastic change.

Comment: I have made a brand new GameObject.  It has nothing except for 2 scripts.  One does this:

        Vector2 newPosition = new Vector2(transform.position.x + 1, transform.position.y);
        rigidbody2D.MovePosition(newPosition);
The other does this:

        Vector2 newPosition = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 1);
        rigidbody2D.MovePosition(newPosition);
Only one of them is being called.  I am going to need to do some research on this.

Comment: This may be of interest to you. (Or maybe not. Who knows.) But if you are curious, this is my dilemma (which you helped me realize):  http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/833269/move-gameobject-with-multiple-scripts.html

Comment: I'll check it out. It might be that `MovePosition` is taking over the movement of the rigid body. It might just be that, if you run it with `AddForce` then it does work.